# How to debug errors in FuncAnimation callback context?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a `FuncAnimation` restartable by using `new_frame_seq()`.

In case of an error like `RuntimeError: xdata and ydata must be the same length` in the animation callback of a `FuncAnimation` how do I debug the error? I'm struggling to figure out why `xdata` and `ydata` are of different size but I can't find the actual call that raises the exception. The call stack shown by the exception only consists of some calls deep in the guts of `Tkinter` and `matplotlib`.

I've tried wrapping my animation function in a big try/catch block but that hasn't worked since the exception seems to be raised in a different context or thread.

Comment: It's hard to tell without any code... But do you know what `xdata` and `ydata` are? If you have a direct access to them, try and print them out at some appropriate place in your code, and if they don't look like what you're expecting, try to figure out what modified them.

Comment: It is not my own code, unfortunately, and it's very dirty. That's why I went without posting it. I have direct access to them but since the code is so dirty and there are multiple calls and multiple levels of nested functions that use global variables and stuff like that I'm not really sure which call raises the exception and where to add my debug prints. It's quite a mess and pretty ugly to look through. I was hoping that there was some trick that I could use to enable Python to show me which line in *our* code caused the error.